# My dropdownlist select onchange is not firing in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

I am very much new to `AngularJS` and I want to get values of `OnChange` of dropdownlist.

Below is my code which I tried

```
<div>
    <select ng-controller="UserSelection as User" ng-model="User.UserSelected" ng-change="onSelectChange()">            
        <option value="SAP_Executive">SAP Executive</option>
        <option value="Fiber_Engineer">Fiber Engineer</option>
        <option value="Fiber_Lead">Fiber Lead</option>
        <option value="CMM">CMM</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Angular code**

```
angular.module('App', [])
 .controller('UserSelection', function () {
  var User = this;      
  User.onSelectChange = function () {
      alert('change value selected');
  };
});
```

My alert is not firing. Please suggest what I am missing here

Comment: Try using `ng-change="User.onSelectChange()"` instead of  `ng-change="onSelectChange()"`

Comment: @SudhirOjha: what is the difference in both the attributes with their values ??

Comment: You have created an alias of your controller.

Comment: perfect..done thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here the following snippet. You have created an alias of your controller but not using it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="App">
    <select ng-controller="UserSelection as User" ng-model="User.UserSelected" ng-change="User.onSelectChange()" ng-init="User.UserSelected='--select--'">
        <option value="--select--">--select--</option>            
        <option value="SAP_Executive">SAP Executive</option>
        <option value="Fiber_Engineer">Fiber Engineer</option>
        <option value="Fiber_Lead">Fiber Lead</option>
        <option value="CMM">CMM</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
 angular.module('App', [])
 .controller('UserSelection', function () {
  var User = this;      
  User.onSelectChange = function () {
      alert('change value selected');
  };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can I get default value "--Select--" on load ?

Comment: why blank value is coming, need to remove that ?

Comment: Which value you want default selected ?

Comment: I want `--Select--` as default

Comment: @BN done you can use `ng-selected `. I have updated my answer.

Comment: did u checked the snippet, after selecting the default gets again selected.. have a look

Comment: Done. check again